# Entropy viewed as the amount of stored information in a volume?

Tags: entropy, information

First, can entropy be completely defined as in the title of this question?

Second, just an example question: If you cast a shadow on a wall are you decreasing the entropy of the wall?

Third, how does this relate to the wild idea that we may live in a holographic universe?

Comment: You are confusing the concepts. The idea of holographic universe is a quite hand wavy concept of correspondence which has been simplified to the analogy of hologram. The idea is that the information inside a 4D spacetime can be described as that on a lower dimensional deSitter space. The analogy of hologram is quite far fetched and is almost as wrong in this context, as a tablecloth is while describing spacetime.

Answer (score 0):

> Entropy viewed as the amount of stored information in a volume
>   First, can entropy be completely defined as in the title of this question?

No, it can't.

> *Entropy is simply a quantitative measure of what the second law of thermodynamics describes: the spreading of energy until it is evenly spread.  Information entropy, which is a measure of information communicated by systems that are affected by data noise.
>   Thermodynamic entropy is part of the science of heat energy. It is a measure of how organized or disorganized energy is in a system of atoms or molecules.* read more on https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy
>
> Second, just an example question: If you cast a shadow on a wall are you decreasing the entropy of the wall?

The entropy of a wall is a measure of the amount of disorder in the bricks molecular makeup, or the disorder in the clumps of sand in the mortar,  there are lots of ways you can measure entropy, depends on what you are measuring.

> Third, how does this relate to the wild idea that we may live in a holographic universe?

I don't know what you mean by this statement. But as you say, the holographic universe is a wild idea, we don't  currently have evidence to support it as far as I know.

Comment: But, what about Maxwell's demon:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell's_demon

Comment: What (in particular) about him/her/it? :)  It would take energy to do the sorting, increasing the entropy, as I remember the argument, but I would need to check.  I am sure there is some duplicate related question regarding this thought experiment.